# Vanuatu Passport Holder transit for 21hours in Seoul

Tags: transit, seoul

Few Vanuatu Passport Holders are transitting in Incheon, Seoul for 21hours going to Israel...do they need to have visas??

Comment: Usual question - are both legs on a single booking (one PNR) or will they need to clear immigration to reclaim luggage before checking in for the onward flight?